# How to implement a Jakarta EE @DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition

Tags: java, jakarta-ee-security-api

I want to update my existing Jakarta EE 8 application running in wildfly to the new Jakarta EE Securtiy API 3.0 using with Wildfly 27

My old configuration in the wildfly standalone.xml file looks like this:

```xml
    <jdbc-realm name="myrealm">
        <principal-query sql="select PASSWORD from USERID where ID=? AND PASSWORD IS NOT NULL" data-source="office">
          <simple-digest-mapper algorithm="simple-digest-sha-256" password-index="1" hash-encoding="hex"/>
        </principal-query>
        <principal-query sql="select GROUP_ID from USERID_USERGROUP where ID=?" data-source="office">
          <attribute-mapping>
            <attribute to="Roles" index="1"/>
          </attribute-mapping>
        </principal-query>
    </jdbc-realm>
```

Now my question is how does this should look when I use the `@DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition` ?

```java
@DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition( //
        dataSourceLookup = "java:comp/env/jdbc/securityDS", //
        callerQuery = "select PASSWORD from USERID where ID=? AND PASSWORD IS NOT NULL", //
        groupsQuery = "select GROUP_ID from USERID_USERGROUP where ID=?", //
        priority = 30, //
        hashAlgorithm = PasswordHash.class)
@ApplicationScoped
  public class DatabaseStore {
}
```

How can I define the 'simple-digest-sha-256' algorithm?

And how can I provide additional parameters like attribute mapping which I use in my old Wildfly standalone.xml file?